# PHP - How to get the array value (like [0], [1], [2]) when you find the item with array_search

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I'm trying to be specific as possible but here I go.

I got 2 arrays, f.e.:

`$foo = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");`
`$fee = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");`

'one' matches 'a', 'two' matches 'b', 'three' matches 'c' etc.

Let's say I type `"abc"` in the text input. How do I get `"onetwothree"` as output?

I was thinking. If I can get the array value of the input text, I can use that to find the array item I want.

I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense, but for those who understand, I appreciate the help.

Update (Example):

Input: `'a'`
Output: `'one'`

Trying to figure out: 
In this case the key value of `'a'` is [1].
I want to know how I can use a command or anything to get that value when I search `'a'` with `array_search`. Maybe I'm using a more complicated way... Any suggestions to do this faster are welcome! :)

Comment: Yeah man, I'm still trying to

Comment: In your example - why when entering `a` will you get `b` - I thought you wanted `one`?

Comment: Please help us help you. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Nigel, I'm sorry for the confusion, I meant 'one', sorry. I need to know how to connect those keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$foo = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$fee = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');

$output = '';
$text = 'abc';
```

- We can split the text to an array, each character as an element.
- Search for the index
- Make sure the index also exists in the other array
- Use the index to append the matching string.

```
foreach(str_split($text) as $char) {
    $index = array_search($char, $foo);
    if($index !== false && isset($fee[$index])) $output .= $fee[$index];
}

echo $output;
```

> onetwothree

Answer (score -1):

Just get the index of `$foo` array which you are typing and get the values from `$fee` array and just concat them.